# Conexion de base de datos access con JAVA

Tags: java, ms-access

Saludos no se por que no corre la conexión sera por el `jackcess` que estara obsoleto  o por la versión de mi jdk 1.8? porque ya agrege el `JAR` `UCanAccess` 4.0.4 a las librerias a traves de netbeans

```
package Frames;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
/**
 *
* @author 
*/


// creando la clase conexion para conectar a la base de datos en Access
public class Conexion {
static Connection conn = null;
static String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";


static String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\xxxx\\xxx.accdb";

public static Connection ejecutarConexion(){
    try{
        if(conn==null){
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado");

        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        conn = null;
    }
    return conn;
}


public static void main(String [] args){
    Connection cn= Conexion.ejecutarConexion();
}
}
```

El **error** es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta en el `driver` estas usando este:

```
static String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
```

Prueba con este otro a mi me ha funcionado

```
this.controlador="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
```

Y te falta `createStatement` pero te dejo este ejemplo de mi clase de conexión para que te des una idea de las partes que te faltaron

```
public class connectBD {


private Connection conexion;
private Statement sentencia;
private final String controlador;
private final String nombre_bd;
private final String usuarioBD;
private final String passwordBD;





public connectBD(){

    this.controlador="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

    this.nombre_bd="C:\\Users\\Raul\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BD_Access\\Prueba_Java.accdb";

    this.usuarioBD="";

    this.passwordBD="";
}



public boolean EstablecerConexion() throws SQLException{
    try{
        conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+this.nombre_bd,this.usuarioBD,this.passwordBD);
    }catch (SQLException e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al realizar la conexion "+e);
         return false;
    }



    try {
        this.sentencia=this.conexion.createStatement(
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al crear el objeto sentencia "+e);
        return false;

    }

    return true;
}



public ResultSet EjecutarSentencia( String sql) throws SQLException{
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = this.sentencia.executeQuery(sql);
    return rs;
}

}
```