# Ayuda para conectar Java con una BD de Access

Tags: base-de-datos, eclipse, ms-access

Hice una conexión de Java con Access, y la conexión ya está hecha correctamente, después hice una interfaz por la cual puedo a través de ella insertar, editar y guardar datos para la base de datos pero esta no me funciona, les dejo el código de la conexión:

```
package Conexion;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexionAccess {
    static Connection con = null;
    static String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    static String url ="jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Administrador\\Documents\\Mueblelo.accdb;memory=false";

    public static Connection getConexion (){    
        try {
            if (con==null) {    
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection (url);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conexion correcta");
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
            con = null;                 
            } 
            return con;     
        }

        public static void main (String []args){

            Connection con = ConexionAccess.getConexion();          
        }

    }
```

Y éste es el código de la interfaz:

```
package Conexion;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class FrmPrueba extends JFrame {


      ;

     {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    JTable tblPrueba;
    JScrollPane jspPrueba;
    DefaultTableModel dtmPrueba;
    String titulos [] = {"ID", "Precio", "Categoria", "Descripcion", "Precio A"};

    JTextField txtID, txtPrecio, txtCategoria, txtDescripcion, txtPrecioA;
    JLabel lblID, lblPrecio, lblCategoria, lblDescripcion, lblPrecioA;

    Connection con = null;
    JButton btnGuardar, btnNuevo;   

    public FrmPrueba (){

        //setVisible(true);

        btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnNuevo = new JButton("Nuevo");

        txtID = new JTextField();
        txtPrecio = new JTextField();
        txtCategoria = new JTextField();
        txtDescripcion = new JTextField();
        txtPrecioA = new JTextField();


        lblID = new JLabel("ID");
        lblPrecio = new JLabel("Precio");
        lblCategoria = new JLabel("Categoria");
        lblDescripcion = new JLabel("Descripcion");
        lblPrecioA = new JLabel("Precio A");


        dtmPrueba = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
        tblPrueba = new JTable(dtmPrueba);
        jspPrueba = new JScrollPane (tblPrueba);    

        add(jspPrueba);

        add(txtID);
        add(txtPrecio);
        add(txtCategoria);
        add(txtDescripcion);
        add(txtPrecioA);
        add(lblID);
        add(lblPrecio);
        add(lblCategoria);
        add(lblDescripcion);
        add(lblPrecioA);

        add(btnGuardar);
        add(btnNuevo);

        jspPrueba.setBounds(20,200,550,200);

        lblID.setBounds(20,20,200,20);
        txtID.setBounds(120,20,200,20);

        lblPrecio.setBounds(20,50,100,20);
        txtPrecio.setBounds(120,50,200,20);

        lblCategoria.setBounds(20,80,100,20);
        txtCategoria.setBounds(120,80,200,20);

        lblDescripcion.setBounds(20,110,100,20);
        txtDescripcion.setBounds(120,110,200,20);

        lblPrecioA.setBounds(20,140,110,20);
        txtPrecioA.setBounds(120,140,200,20);

        btnNuevo.setBounds(390, 100, 100, 25);
        btnGuardar.setBounds(390, 140, 100, 25);

        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                btnGuardarActionPerform(evt);
            }
        });

        btnNuevo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                btnNuevoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });


        tblPrueba.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
                tblPruebaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        mostrar();

        }

        protected void btnNuevoActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtID.setText("");
            txtPrecio.setText("");
            txtCategoria.setText("");
            txtDescripcion.setText("");
            txtPrecioA.setText("");
    }

        protected void tblPruebaMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int file = tblPrueba.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
            txtID.setText(tblPrueba.getValueAt(file, 0).toString());
            txtPrecio.setText(tblPrueba.getValueAt(file, 1).toString());
            txtCategoria.setText(tblPrueba.getValueAt(file, 2).toString());
            txtDescripcion.setText(tblPrueba.getValueAt(file, 3).toString());
            txtPrecioA.setText(tblPrueba.getValueAt(file, 4).toString());

    }

    protected void btnGuardaractionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try{
            con = ConexionAccess.getConexion();
            if(txtID.getText().equals("")){
                String sql = "Insert into tbl(Id, Precio, Categoria, Descripcion, PrecioA values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtPrecio.getText());
                pst.setString(3, txtCategoria.getText());
                pst.setString(4, txtDescripcion.getText());
                pst.setString(5, txtPrecioA.getText());
                int n = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(n>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se registró de forma correcta");
                }

            }else{
                String sql = "update tbl set Id = ?, set = Precio, Categoria = ?, Descripcion = ?, PrecioA = ? where Id = ?)";  
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, txtID.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtPrecio.getText());
                pst.setString(3, txtCategoria.getText());
                pst.setString(4, txtDescripcion.getText());
                pst.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(txtPrecioA.getText()));
                int n = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(n>0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se actualizó de forma correcta");
                }
            }}catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        mostrar();
        txtID.setText("");
        txtPrecio.setText("");
        txtCategoria.setText("");
        txtDescripcion.setText("");
        txtPrecioA.setText("");
        mostrar();

    }   

    public void mostrar (){
        try{
            con = ConexionAccess.getConexion();
            DefaultTableModel MUEBLELOS= (DefaultTableModel) tblPrueba.getModel();
            String dts[] = new String[5];
            String sql = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(value1, value2, value3)";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()); 
                dts[0] = rs.getString(1);
                dts[1] = rs.getString(2);
                dts[2] = rs.getString(3);
                dts[3] = rs.getString(4);
                dts[4] = rs.getString(5);
                MUEBLELOS.addRow(dts); 

          tblPrueba.setModel(MUEBLELOS);     
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        FrmPrueba mi = new FrmPrueba(); 
        mi.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mi.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mi.setLayout (null);
        mi.setTitle ("Mueblelo | ¡Bienvenido!");
        mi.setSize(600, 500);
        mi.setVisible(true);
        //Connection on = ConexionAccess.obtenerConexion();


            }   

   public FrmPrueba(String title, GraphicsConfiguration gc, JTable tblPrueba,
            JScrollPane jspPrueba, DefaultTableModel dtmPrueba,
            String[] titulos, JTextField txtId, JTextField txtPrecio,
            JTextField txtCategoria, JTextField txtDescripcion,
            JTextField txtPrecioA, JLabel lblId, JLabel lblPrecio,
            JLabel lblCategoria, JLabel lblDescripcion, JLabel lblPrecioA,
            Connection con, JButton btnGuardar, JButton btnNuevo) {
        super(title, gc);
        this.tblPrueba = tblPrueba;
        this.jspPrueba = jspPrueba;
        this.dtmPrueba = dtmPrueba;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.txtID = txtId;
        this.txtPrecio = txtPrecio;
        this.txtCategoria = txtCategoria;
        this.txtDescripcion = txtDescripcion;
        this.txtPrecioA = txtPrecioA;
        this.lblID = lblId;
        this.lblPrecio = lblPrecio;
        this.lblCategoria = lblCategoria;
        this.lblDescripcion = lblDescripcion;
        this.lblPrecioA = lblPrecioA;
        this.con = con;
        this.btnGuardar = btnGuardar;
        this.btnNuevo = btnNuevo;
    }

protected void btnGuardarActionPerforme (ActionEvent evt) {


    }




    protected void btnGuardarActionPerform(ActionEvent evt) {


    }


    }
```

Al correr la conexion con Access no hay problema, pero al correr la interfaz, esta aparece pero me saltan los siguientes errores además de eso los datos no se guardan al introducirlos:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: TABLE_NAME
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:218)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.mostrar(FrmPrueba.java:196)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.<init>(FrmPrueba.java:123)
    at Conexion.FrmPrueba.main(FrmPrueba.java:211)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: TABLE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:216)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: usuario no tiene privilegios suficientes o objeto no encontrado: TABLE_NAME
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRangeVariableForDataChange(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Estoy usando Eclipse, les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran!!!

Comment: Todo parece indicar que como dice el error, el usuario con el que intentas acceder a la base no tiene privilegios.

Comment: Esa base de datos la hice yo mismo, ¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? por cierto muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157868/conexion-de-base-de-datos-access-con-java te puede guiar mejor de como crear la conexión entre Java y Access, ya que en tu conexión no veo que le pases usuario y contraseña.

Comment: Muchas gracias si me ayudó!!